# how can I combine a list of Result<> in F#?

Tags: f#

with this code:

```
let a = [3; 4; 5; 6; 7]
let check x = if x % 2 = 0 then Ok x else Error x
let b = a |> List.map check
```

how can I summarize B as:

- if all Ok, then Ok<int list>
- if any Error, then Error<int list>

I could make a method that does this, but I can't help thinking that this has to be built in, or there has to be a clever simple way to make it happen (I have FsToolkit.ErrorHandling btw, in case it's built in there.

Comment: What would be the `int list` inside `Error`?

Comment: the collection of all the error terms; so if all ok, then ok has a list of all the ok values, and if any is error, then error has a list of all the errors

Comment: You're returning the value in a `Result<int, int>`, which is isomorphic to `bool * int`. Personally, I would just return that tuple type instead and use `List.partition >> fst` to split them.

Comment: This request for such a function is not so uncommon, [see this](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus/issues/51#issuecomment-508284080) . So with F#+ you can get it by doing `let x: Result<_, _ list> = traverse (first result) (map Validation.ofResult b) |> Validation.toResult`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need is `traverseResultA` in the list functions for `FsToolkit.ErrorHandling`. See [traverseResultA](https://demystifyfp.gitbook.io/fstoolkit-errorhandling/list/traverseresulta) where it says "This is applicative, collecting all errors. Compare the example ...with traverseResultM." (The latter is a monad which gets the first error).

```
#r "nuget: FsToolkit.ErrorHandling"
open FsToolkit.ErrorHandling

let a = [3; 4; 5; 6; 7]
let aOk = [4;6]
let aError = [3;5;7]
let check x = if x % 2 = 0 then Ok x else Error x
>
val a : int list = [3; 4; 5; 6; 7]
val aOk : int list = [4; 6]
val aError : int list = [3; 5; 7]
val check : x:int -> Result<int,int>


aOk |> List.traverseResultA check
>
val it : Result<int list,int list> = Ok [4; 6]

aError |> List.traverseResultA check
>
val it : Result<int list,int list> = Error [3; 5; 7]

a |> List.traverseResultA check
>
val it : Result<int list,int list> = Error [3; 5; 7]
```

An explicit version could be:

```
let traverseResultA data =
    let value = function Ok x -> x | Error y -> y 
    let filter = function Ok _ -> true | Error _ -> false
    if List.forall filter data then data |> List.map value |> Ok
    else data |> List.filter (not<<filter) |> List.map value |> Error
> 
val traverseResultA : data:Result<'a,'a> list -> Result<'a list,'a list>
```

See also Scott's [article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-4/) for explaining traverse and applicatives versus monads.

Answer (score 4):

You can in fact write the function yourself, once you realize that you want to transform a list of `Result<'a,'b>` into a single `Result<'a list,'b list>`.

```
module Result =
    let ofList arg = 
        (arg, Ok[]) ||> List.foldBack (fun t s ->
        match t, s with
        | Ok x,    Ok xs    -> Ok(x::xs)        // all Ok so far, prepend to state
        | Error e, Ok _     -> Error[e]         // first Error, discard accumulated state
        | Ok _,    Error es -> Error es         // ignore every Ok after first Error
        | Error e, Error es -> Error(e::es) )   // second or later Error, prepend to state
    // val ofList : arg:Result<'a,'b> list -> Result<'a list,'b list>

[3; 4; 5; 6; 7]
|> List.map (fun x -> if x % 2 = 0 then Ok x else Error x)
|> Result.ofList
// val it : Result<int list,int list> = Error [3; 5; 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of cool ideas in the responses here, but IMHO they are overkill for the problem as described. So just for the record, here's a very simple solution:

```
let a = [3; 4; 5; 6; 7]
let check x = (x % 2 = 0), x
let b =
    a
        |> List.map check
        |> List.partition fst
        |> function
            | evens, [] -> Ok evens
            | _, odds -> Error odds
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a `traverse` or `mapM` function.
They are not built into native fsharp, but implementations exists. I will not link to a particular library here since new libraries might pop up later.

You can read more about about it here:
[fsharpforfunandprofit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-4/#traverse)

Comment: See my comment. This function is not a straight `mapM` or `traverse`. In Haskell literature it's called `sequenceBia` (Bia stands for bi-applicative).

Comment: @Gus No not a simple mapM, but close enough that I might use a mapM if I had one available and wanted to accomplish what the OP is after methinks.

Comment: It is a traverseA. He requires an applicative not a monad.

Comment: Well, they did a free naming in that library. bur the original name is `traverseBia`, which is `sequenceBia id` and the requirement is `biapplicative`.