# How to split F# result type list into lists of inner type

Tags: f#

I have a list/sequence as follows `Result<DataEntry, exn> []`. This list is populated by calling multiple API endpoints in parallel based on some user inputs.

I don't care if some of the calls fail as long as at least 1 succeeds. I then need to perform multiple operations on the success list.

My question is how to partition the Result list into `exn []` and `DataEntry []` lists. I tried the following:

```
// allData is Result<DataEntry, exn> []

let filterOutErrors (input: Result<DataEntry, exn>) =
    match input with
    | Ok v -> true
    | _ -> false

let values, err = allData |> Array.partition filterOutErrors
```

This in principle meets the requirement since `values` contains all the success cases but understandably the compiler can't infer the types so both `values` and `err` contains `Result<DataEntry, exn>`.

Is there any way to split a list of result `Result<Success, Err>` such that you end up with separate lists of the inner type?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247826/how-can-i-combine-a-list-of-result-in-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the good and the bad like this.

```
let values =
    allData
    |> Array.choose (fun r ->
        match r with
        | Result.Ok ok -> Some ok
        | Result.Error _ -> None)

let err =
    allData
    |> Array.choose (fun r ->
        match r with
        | Result.Ok _ -> None
        | Result.Error error -> Some error)
```

You seem confused about whether you have arrays or lists. The F# code you use, in the snippet and in your question text, all points to use of arrays, in spite of you several times mentioning lists.

It has recently been recommended that we use `array` instead of the `[]` symbol in types, since there are inconsistencies in the way F# uses the symbol `[]` to mean `list` in some places, and `array` in other places. There is also the symbol `[||]` for arrays, which may add more confusion.

So that would be recommending `Result<DataEntry,exn> array` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. On the terminology point thanks for the clarification. I was mainly just casting around for a generic word for all kinds of `Seq`, so it could be a Array or List or Seq interchangeably but I guess `seq` is standard? I'll update my internal standard notation for array types accordingly.

Comment: Yes, the confusion we generally have is only about List vs Array notation, and newcomers to the language is thrown off all the time by it. Hence the recommendation to instead spell out `array` and `list` in type annotations. There's still the confusion that `[]` means list and `[||]` means array elsewhere in the source, but I guess there is little that can be done about it at this time.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to split a list of result `Result<Success, Err>` such that you end up with separate lists of the inner type?

Remember that `Seq` / `List` / `Array` are foldable, so you can use `fold` to convert a `Seq` / `List` / `Array` of `'T`s into any other type `'S`. Here you want to go from `[]Result<DataEntry, exn>` to, e.g., the tuple `list<DataEntry> * list<exn>`. We can define the following folder function, that takes an initial state `s` of type `list<'a> * list<'b>` and a Result `Result<'a, 'b>` and returns your tuple of lists `list<'a> * list<'b>`:

```ml
let listFolder s r =  
    match r with
    | Ok data -> (data :: (fst s), snd s)
    | Error err -> (fst s, err :: (snd s))
```

then you can fold over your array as follows:

```ml
let (values, err) =  Seq.fold listFolder ([], []) allData
```

Comment: If you swap the arguments for listFolder, and swap the last two arguments for Seq.fold, and use Seq.foldBack instead, then the resulting lists will have the same order as the original list, instead of the opposite order.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Víctor G. Adán is functional, but it's a downside that the API requires you to pass in two empty lists, exposing the internal implementation.
You could wrap this into a "starter" function, but then the code grows, requires nested functions or using modules and the intention is obscured.

The answer from Bent Tranberg, while more readable requires two passes of the data, and it seems inefficient to map into Option type just to be able to filter on it using .Choose.

I propose KISS'ing it with some good old mutation.

```
open System.Collections.Generic

let splitByOkAndErrors xs =
    let oks = List<'T>()
    let errors = List<'V>()
    for x in xs do
        match x with
        | Ok v -> oks.Add v
        | Error e -> errors.Add e
    (oks |> seq, errors |> seq)
```

I know I know, mutation, yuck right? I believe you should not shy away from that even in F#, use the right tool for every situation: the mutation is kept local to the function, so it's still pure. The API is clean just taking in the list of Result to split, there is no concepts like folding, recursive calls, list cons pattern matching etc. to understand, and the function won't reverse the input list, you also have the option to return array or seq, that is, you are not confined to a linked list that can only be appended to in O(1) in the head - which in my experience seldom fits well into business case, win win win in my book.

I general, I hope to see F# grow into a more multi-paradigm programming language in the community's mind. It's nice to see these functional solutions, but I fear they scare some people away unnecessarily, as F# is already multi-paradigm!